# dynamic table input value calculations

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of a dynamic table cell. following is the code, but i only get undefined

Javascript and HTML given below:

```js
function calcTot(i) {

            unitPrice = document.getElementById("invoice_details").rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML.value;//gets the unit price for the item
            alert(unitPrice);
            quantity = document.getElementById("invoice_details").rows[i].cells[7].childNodes[0].value;
            //alert(quantity);
            dis = document.getElementById("invoice_details").rows[i].cells[8].children[0].value;
           //alert(dis);
            final_amt = (parseFloat(unitPrice) * parseFloat(quantity)) - (parseFloat(unitPrice) * parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(dis)) / 100;
           //alert(final_amt);
            document.getElementById("invoice_details").rows[i].cells[9].childNodes[0].value = final_amt.toFixed(2);
            //calcTotal();



        }
```

```html
<tbody id="generate_invoice_table">
<tr>
<td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="57" name="item_id[]"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="Toyota" name="supplier_name[]"></td>
<td><input hidden="" class="form-control" readonly="" value="Item" name="type[]"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="Fan Belt Aqua" name="item_description[]"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="1" name="available_qty[]"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="12000.00" name="retail_price[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="0" class="form-control text-right" name="qty[]" onmousemove="calcTot(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="0" class="form-control text-right" name="discount[]" onmousemove="calcTot(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="price[]"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: could you also provide your html? And the function itself looks like anti pattern to me due to the variables had been declared out of the function's body

Comment: table id is invoice_details

Comment: Your `tbody`'s id is `generate_invoice_table` yet you are trying to fetch something whose id is `invoice_table`. In the provided snippet there's no element whose id is `invoice_table`

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks I got this sorted out....